# Configuring access for 30 AWS CodeCommit repositories

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit

I've 30 AWS CodeCommit repositories and for them, I need to manage Permissions.

- User 1: Needs access to 26 AWS CodeCommit repositories
- User 2: Needs access to 4 AWS CodeCommit repositories
- User 3: Needs access to 12 AWS CodeCommit repositories
- User 4: Needs access to 22 AWS CodeCommit repositories
- User 5: Needs access to 18 AWS CodeCommit repositories

Due to AWS Limitations, am not able to configure permissions exceeding 20 repositories.

I need reference links on how should the IAM access policies be configured for groups / managed policies exceeding 10.

Comment: Could you create a Group for each repository, and then add the Users to the appropriate Groups? Alternatively, create a Managed Policy for each repository, and attach the appropriate policies to each User. Try to avoid putting permissions directly on Users.

Comment: Tried that, but AWS has hard limitation of assigning at max 10 managed policies. That route doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is an IAM policy limitation. I am afraid there's nothing much we can do on CodeCommit side now. However, if two or more repositories have the same CodeCommit managed policies, you could list all of them in the same managed policy, so you don't have to create a managed policy for each repository. Also, you could use the wildcards pattern to match the resources (repository names). In this way, you don’t need to list all the repositories in the resource-statement.

Comment: So this means I can't have fine grained  control over multiple repositories for the scenarios I mentioned above... If that is the case, then how should I design the policies so as to allow user to have access to multiple repositories?
Currently, I've defined inline policies for the users, but am sure that it is not the right way to manage the things out...
Am I missing something on AWS Services full maturity offerings?

Comment: Did you create an inline policy for each of your repository? Do all the repositories need to have different permission setting in your use case?

Comment: I didn't created inline policies for each repository. I created online policies for each user. You are right that my each repository needs different permissions for each user. To add, each repository name is different and can't use wild card characters for assignment of policies.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your use case correctly. That's say there is a user, who needs accesses for 20 repositories. Does all of these 20 repositories need to have different permission setting? (for example: repo1 only needs readonly permission and repo2 needs list*..etc)

Comment: Not sure where there is mix up for the explanation. Here is the simplified version:
User 1: Needs full access to 26 AWS CodeCommit repositories and no access to other repositories
User 2: Needs full access to 4 AWS CodeCommit repositories and no access to other repositories
User 3: Needs full access to 12 AWS CodeCommit repositories and no access to other repositories
User 4: Needs full access to 22 AWS CodeCommit repositories and no access to other repositories
User 5: Needs full access to 18 AWS CodeCommit repositories and no access to other repositories

Comment: Above example clearly indicates that in my scenario, each repository will have different set of users with full access. For any repository, a user can have either full access or no access. Hope this simplifies.

Comment: If that is your use case I guess each user only need to have one inline policy:

Comment: {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCodeCommit",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "codecommit:*",
            "Resource": [
                <list of the repos>
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Comment: That's what I've done and mentioned.
Surprised to see this kind of awkward limitation on the repositories from AWS. AWS never thought of this kind of scenarios? Really surprising...

Comment: I tried to set up a policy with more than 20 repositories listed in 
 "Resource" which works for me. Did you hit the inline policy size limitation(user policy size cannot exceed 2,048 characters)? If so, I would recommend you to rename your repository, so you can use wild card pattern to match the repository names.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142208/discussion-between-sanket-shah-and-hsiao-tung-chen).